# std::function -> function pointer

Tags: c++, bind, functor

Here is a code:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std::tr1;

typedef void(*fp)(void);

void foo(void)
{

}

void f(fp)
{

}

int main()
{
  function<void(void)> fun = foo;
  f(fun); // error
  f(foo); // ok
}
```

Originally i need to make a function pointer from non-static class method because i need to save data between function callings. I tried `std::tr1::bind` and `boost::bind`, but they return functional object, not pointer, which, as i can see, can't be "casted" to pure functional pointer. While the function signature (`SetupIterateCabinet`) demands a pure func pointer exactly.

I need an advise how to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: See also [c++ - How do I pass a std::function object to a function taking a function pointer? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562437/how-do-i-pass-a-stdfunction-object-to-a-function-taking-a-function-pointer) (although it's more general than this question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've greatly oversimplified your real problem and turned your question into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166663). Let's get back to your *real* question: how to call [`SetupIterateCabinet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377404%28VS.85%29.aspx) with a non-static member function as a callback.

Given some class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    UINT MyCallback(UINT Notification, UINT_PTR Param1, UINT_PTR Param2)
    {
        /* impl */
    }
};
```

In order to use `MyClass::MyCallback` as the third argument to `SetupIterateCabinet`, you need to pass a `MyClass*` for the `Context` argument and use a plain shim function to take that `Context` argument and do the right thing with it:

```
UINT MyClassCallback(PVOID Context, UINT Notification, UINT_PTR Param1, UINT_PTR Param2)
{
    return static_cast<MyClass*>(Context)->MyCallback(Notification, Param1, Param2);
}

int main()
{
    MyClass mc;
    SetupIterateCabinet(_T("some path"), 0, MyClassCallback, &mc);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't convert a `std::function` to a function pointer(you can do the opposite). You should use either function pointers, or `std::function`s. If you can use `std::function` instead of pointers, then you should.

This makes your code work:

```
typedef function<void(void)> fp;
```

Comment: The only thing I'll add is that using std::function also allows you to use a type with operator () overloaded.  Excellent answer.

Comment: How do you propose he change `SetupIterateCabinet` (a C API) to take a C++ object?

Comment: @ildjarn "You should use either function pointers, or `std::function`". If he can't use `std::function` then he ought to use function pointers, unless he wants to wrap his `std::function`s around static functions, but that's not going to be pretty.

Comment: @ildjarn you can't and he didn't state anything else. In those cases I usually have a wrapper plain C function that, using the "user context" most often passed to callbacks (SetupIterateCabinet offers one as well) to route the callback to some C++ thing.

Comment: @fontanini: So, there is no way to pass object having state?

Comment: @zerm : Exactly my point, and the point this answer entirely misses.

Comment: I thought `SetupIterateCabinet` was a function OP had created, I didn't know it was a Windows API function, nor did I know that you could pass a "context" parameter.

Comment: @ildjarn yes, but it was more a fault of the OP, so I felt that downvote was not justified. Good thing you've already provided an answers better matching OP's intend, though ;)

Comment: @zerm : If the OP hadn't specifically mentioned `SetupIterateCabinet` then I agree that the downvote wouldn't be justified. As it is...