# Using C++ member function to handle a callback that takes simple static function pointer

Tags: c++, oop, callback, raspberry-pi

I haven't used C++ in ages. Between what I've forgotten and what has changed in C++ over time, I'm really banging my head against the wall trying to do something that would be trivially easy in JavaScript, or any other language where functions are objects, and not just simple pointers.

I think I understand the basic problem: A class member function only exists in once place in memory (there isn't a different copy of it for each class instance). The only way the function knows what "this" is is because an instance pointer is passed along as an invisible first argument to every function call. A plain-old C-style callback isn't going to know anything about passing that instance pointer.

What I need is a new function that is somehow bound to my class instance, one which knows how to pass "this" along to the member function. That's the function I need to use as a callback.

But I don't know for sure how to dynamically create such a function. I think the code below is on the right track (except for casting pointer types), but it does bother me a bit because it seems like that there'd have to be some dynamic memory allocation going on, and if so, some way to track that allocation and do clean-up later.

```
class SignalMonitor {
    int dataPin;
    unsigned short timings[RING_BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned long lastSignalChange = 0;
    int dataIndex = 0;
    int syncCount = 0;

    void signalHasChanged();

  public:
    SignalMonitor(int);
};

SignalMonitor::SignalMonitor(int dataPin) {
  this->dataPin = dataPin;
  function<void()> callback = bind(&SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged, this);
  wiringPiISR(dataPin, INT_EDGE_BOTH, callback);
}

void SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged() {
  unsigned long now = micros();
  int duration = (int) min(now - this->lastSignalChange, 10000ul);
  this->lastSignalChange = now;
  cout << duration << '\n';
}
```

I feel like this is close to what I want, but I'm getting this error:

```
acu-rite-433Mhz-reader.cpp:58:72: error: invalid cast from type ‘std::function<void()>’ to type ‘void*’
   wiringPiISR(dataPin, INT_EDGE_BOTH, reinterpret_cast<void *>(callback));
                                                                        ^
```

Here's the call signature of the function I'm trying to pass this callback to:

> int wiringPiISR (int pin, int edgeType,  void (*function)(void))

I've found a number of similar issues discussed when searching on this topic, but they either don't quite match what I'm trying to do, or assume much more familiarity with C++ than I currently possess. (All I remember about function pointer types is that they can get hellishly ugly very quickly!)

I tried to use lambda function as a solution, but that led to an error (besides a type mismatch error) about something being "temporary", which I'm assuming meant that the lambda function's scope was temporary.

Comment: `std::function`, being an object, can't be converted to a function pointer. There are workarounds, but they range from awkward to horrifying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562437/how-do-i-pass-a-stdfunction-object-to-a-function-taking-a-function-pointer . The least awful I've seen is to use a function that calls a global `std::function`, and to just accept using a global.

Comment: I take it you will have more than one `this`, multiple instances of SignalMonitor. I just went around the block, (again, done this before). And there should be an elegant way as long as `this` is valid. I'm going to look more tomorrow, I want to know too. I'm watching this post.

Comment: @parktomatomi, a global won't work because there can be multiple instances of the class, and there's no way to know before the callback is triggered which of those instances should be set up to receive it.

Comment: Will you have multiple monitors for the same (pin, event) pair?

Comment: @jhk, that was something that I wanted to allow for. It's been a long time since I worked on this code -- this part of my Raspberry Pi code for reading wireless temperature sensors has been working smoothly for nearly two years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a far from ideal solution (I'm beginning to think there are no ideal solutions here), but it works for me in this particular case where there aren't likely to be very many instances of my `SignalMonitor` class in use at the same time.

First, I turned my `signalHasChanged` class method into a static method that takes an instance as an argument. (I could have kept the method as a class method by going through some hairy type-casting, but it wasn't worth it.)

Then I made ten almost-identical indirect callback functions:

```
void smCallback0() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[0]); }
void smCallback1() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[1]); }
void smCallback2() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[2]); }
void smCallback3() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[3]); }
void smCallback4() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[4]); }
void smCallback5() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[5]); }
void smCallback6() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[6]); }
void smCallback7() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[7]); }
void smCallback8() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[8]); }
void smCallback9() { SignalMonitor::signalHasChanged(monitors[9]); }
```

Then I stuck all of those functions into an array:

```
void (*_smCallbacks[MAX_MONITORS])() = {
  smCallback0, smCallback1, smCallback2, smCallback3, smCallback4,
  smCallback5, smCallback6, smCallback7, smCallback8, smCallback9
};
```

Along with the `monitors` array, which is an array of `SignalHandler` pointers, this gives me ten available callback slots. (`_smCallbacks` is copied into `smCallbacks` as a way to get around foreward reference problems.)

The `init` method for `SignalMonitor` simply searches for an available slot, plugs itself in, then sets the callback:

```
void SignalMonitor::init() {
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MONITORS; ++i) {
    if (monitors[i] == NULL) {
      callbackIndex = i;
      monitors[i] = this;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (callbackIndex < 0)
    throw "Maximum number of SignalMonitor instances reached";

  wiringPiISR(dataPin, INT_EDGE_BOTH, smCallbacks[callbackIndex]);
}
```

There's also a destructor to free up the callback slots:

```
SignalMonitor::~SignalMonitor() {
  if (callbackIndex >= 0)
    monitors[callbackIndex] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I see the correspondence between what you were saying and my method now, the difference being mine isn't per pin, but per instance. That's worth an up vote for your answer to then. :)

Answer (score 1):

It may help to consider the traditional way of handling a similar issue. Other APIs have been designed where instead of `void(*function)(void)`, `wiringPiISR` would expect a function `void(*function)(void *)`.  This allows the use of

```
static void signalHasChanged(void *p) {
  static_cast<SignalMonitor*>(p)->signalHasChanged();
}
```

This is not a general solution, but because Raspberry Pi has a limited number of GPIO pins, and you can't have more callback functions than you have pins, you might be able to create one callback function per pin.  Then, you need a global data structure that maps the interrupt pin to which SignalMonitor instance (or instances) it should signal. The constructor would register the 'this' object to a specific pin, then set the appropriate callback function based on the pin.

The callback functions would be able to pass a pin argument to a general function, which could then look up the specific SignalMonitor instance and call a class function.

I wouldn't want to do it for 1000 pins, 1000 instances, but this hack should work for anything running on a Pi.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t change the API with which I’m registering my callback, so I’ve got to work with the way it only accepts simple function pointers.