# C++: Cast std::function to gsl_function

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, gsl

I want to use the [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/index.html) and need to cast `std::function` to the [gsl_function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/roots.html?highlight=gsl_function#c.gsl_function), which is of type `double (* function) (double x, void * params)`.

Until now I simply tried:

```
class Numerics {
 public:
  ....
  double integrate(function<double(double)> &func) {
    double result, error;
    gsl_function F;
    F.function = static_cast<(*)(double, void *)>( func );
    gsl_integration_qag(&F, 0, 1, epsabs_, epsrel_, 1000, 6, w_, &result, &error);
    return result;
  }
  ...
};
```

, which hands me back the error

> type name requires a specifier
>         or qualifier

Comment: You can't `static_cast` a `std::function` to function pointer. `std::function` might contain more information than a simple function pointer.

Comment: You cannot convert a `std::function` to a function pointer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555464/stdfunction-function-pointer) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::function -> function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555464/stdfunction-function-pointer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::function` is a type erasing "general functor" holder from the standard library. It's not implicitly convertible to regular function pointers, nor should you attempt to do it, since you'd just end up shooting yourself in the foot. You need to wrap the call to `func` with a proper regular function that conforms to the `gsl_function::function` typedef.

`gsl_function::function` accepts a `void*` as extra function parameter. That's your hook for passing an object like `std::function` into it, to facilitate the call. You can use a capture-less lambda (which will convert implicitly to a free function pointer) in order to keep things local:

```
gsl_function F = {
  [](double d, void* vf) -> double {
    auto& f = *static_cast<std::function<double(double)>*>(vf);
    return f(d);
  },
  &func
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thx for the very detailed choice of words!